# MySQL Update Value in Table from another Table in same DB

Tags: sql, join

I feel silly asking this, but I cannot get this to work.

I have a table called `import` with 500 rows and two fields (product_id, cost)

I want to update a second table called `product` with 500+ rows matched to import using the product_id field. `product` has two fields (product_id, ac_cost)

I am trying to get product.ac_cost = import.cost. My Google search over the last hour leads me to the syntax below, but I keep getting error 1064 on line 3. I am doing this in HeidiSQL.

> UPDATE P
>   SET P.ac_cost = I.cost
>   FROM product P
>   INNER JOIN import I ON I.product_id = P.product_id

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the statement:

```
UPDATE product P
 INNER JOIN import I ON I.product_id = P.product_id
 SET P.ac_cost = I.cost
```

Comment: Added the table name to line 1, and that did the trick! Thanks @Jens.

Comment: @Quads88 Feel free to upvote or accept my answer it it has helped you.